# When creating a datatype in Java, what is the best way to build a constructor to create two different arrays to be part of each instance?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

This is for an algorithms course project I'm working on:

The assignment is to build a datatype representing a traditional mathematical set within a universe.  The methods to be included to manipulate the datatype are things like union, intersection, etc. that require comparison between two instances of the class/datatype.  The way the course wants me to do it by creating an array of booleans to represent the actual set, which is simple enough if you take an array of the actual set, copy it over to a boolean array of the same length, and toggle true or false depending on the presence of the value within the set.    Here's the I've come up with:

```
public class MathSET{

    private int size = 0;
    private Boolean[] currentSet;
    private Character[] universe;

    public MathSET(Character[] uni){
        if (uni.length == 0){
            System.out.println("Set cannot be created, universe cannot be null.");
        } else{
            universe = createUni(uni);
            currentSet = new Boolean[universe.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < universe.length; i++){
                    currentSet[i] = false;
                }
            }
    }
```

createUni leads to a method that sorts, removes duplicates, and resizes the universe array before returning it, and currentSet is created as a boolean array with all of the values set to 'false'.

My biggest problem is, I cannot invoke the complement method, which is supposed to return a new instance of MathSET with the values not included in the current set.  I can make an array with the correct values that represent a complement, but I cannot create a new MathSET (Boolean Array) with the same universal array.   I've also found, that when comparing the universe arrays for two instances of the datatype to make sure that they are actually comparable, the comparison (comparable.universe != this.universe) always gives me the result that the two arrays are not equal and cannot be compared.

I know the issue is with my constructor somewhere, and probably with the nature of my variables, but I'm having trouble seeing what it is.  Just for further clarification, I've confirmed that the createUni method does create a sorted array with the correct values and removes duplicates, and that when printed side by side the two different instances of the MathSET that are supposed to contain the same universal array values are equal in the printing, just not the comparison.

Edit: Since someone asked for the complement method:

```
public MathSET complement(){
    /**Creates a new MathSET boolean array that starts out empty, iterates through current MathSET currentSET array and adds 
    */
    MathSET complement = new MathSET(universe);
    StringBuilder comp = new StringBuilder("Complement to current set: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < currentSet.length; i++){
        if (this.currentSet[i] == false){
            complement.currentSet[i] = true;
            comp.append(complement.currentSet[i] + ", ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(comp);
    return complement;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `complement` method?

Comment: Where are the "multiple constructors", that you tagged the question with? You've only shown one. It sounds like the second constructor's signature should be `Character[] uni, Boolean[] currentSet`

Comment: Added the requested method and fixed the tag.  It was supposed to be constructor only, thank you for pointing that out @Michael.

Comment: What do you mean by "but I cannot create a new MathSET (Boolean Array) with the same universal array."? You certainly created a new MathSET here: `MathSET complement = new MathSET(universe);`. What exactly is wrong with your `complement` method?

Comment: I figured it out, it was an incorrect invocation method in my main method.  I also fiddled around with the universe array comparisons and using Arrays.equals() solved my problem with universal array comparison for the union and intersection methods.  Thank you both so much for your help.